# Error when checking target: expected softmax_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)', Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using Keras for building Conv Net for the first time. My layers are as follows:

```
layers = [
Conv2D(8,kernel_size=(4,4),padding='same',input_shape=( 200, 180,3),kernel_initializer="glorot_normal",data_format="channels_first"),
Activation("relu"),
MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(8,8),padding='same',data_format='channels_first'),
Conv2D(16,(2,2),padding='same',kernel_initializer="glorot_normal"),
Activation("relu"),
MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4,4),padding='same',data_format='channels_first'),
Conv2D(4,(3,3),padding='same',kernel_initializer="glorot_normal"),
Activation("relu"),
MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),padding='same',data_format='channels_first'),
Flatten(),
Dense(2,input_shape=(48,)),
Softmax(axis=-1)
]
#Edit, here is the part for compiling the model and fitting it
model = Sequential(layers)    

model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy" 
metrics=["accuracy"])
trainHistory = model.fit(x=X_train,y=Y_train,batch_size=3,epochs=1000)
```

My labels array is of shape `(,2)`. But when I try to use fit on the model, it gives me the error that `softmax_1` expected to have shape `(1,)`. But I have clearly mentioned units of `Dense` as 2 and softmax returns output of the same dimension as the input.

So where did the 1, came from? I tried to use dummy label array of 1 dimension and it runs. So what am I doing wrong? How do I use 2 dimensional array that I have?

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. Make sure the labels array has a shape of `(n_samples, 2)`.

Comment: yes, it is of shape (num of samples,2). thats why I am not getting what is wrong? why is the error saying (1,) when it clearly is (2,)

Comment: I tested your code and it works on my machine. It is strange that it gives you this error if the target shape is correct. Try upgrading Keras and see if it is resolved. Further, could you please add the code where you construct the model and also the `fit` call?

Comment: @today I added the fit call. pls check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function. This loss function is used when the given labels (i.e. `Y_train`) are encoded as integers (i.e. 0, 1, 2, ...). However, If the labels are one-hot encoded, which seems to be the case in your code, you need to use `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was what was going wrong. The keras documentation page doesn't have proper description for the losses. I was converting from tf to keras, didn't knew which to use for loss.