# Expected last activation layer to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (4,)

Tags: keras, neural-network

Isn't my last layer specifying the number of classes?
What is expecting something of shape 1 ?

I try to class predict images, to 4 groups. My layers are the following:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(96, 96, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# the model so far outputs 3D feature maps (height, width, features)

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4))

model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and data is like:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
fill_mode='nearest')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when checking target: expected softmax\_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)', Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966765/error-when-checking-target-expected-softmax-1-to-have-shape-1-but-got-array)

Comment: Something is not right between the error message and the code you posted.

Comment: could you formalize this please ? ty

Comment: @today the solution solved my question ty